# Solr Out of memory exception

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, lucene

Solr is giving out of memory exception. Index size is small roughly around 30GB. Full Indexing was completed fine. Later while searching maybe when it tries to load the results in memory it starts giving this exception. Though with the same memory allocated to Tomcat and exactly same solr configuration replica on another server it is working perfectly fine. I am working on 64 bit software's including Java & Tomcat on Windows. With smaller index size it is working perfectly fine. I was thinking of increasing the tomcat heap space allocated but then how come on a different server with exactly same system and solr configuration it is working fine?
Any help would be appreciated.

Here are the logs:

The server encountered an internal error (Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change: false in null ------------------------------------------------------------- java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1068) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:579) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414) Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentTermEnum.termInfo(SegmentTermEnum.java:180) at org.apache.lucene.index.TermInfosReader.(TermInfosReader.java:91) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader$CoreReaders.(SegmentReader.java:122) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:652) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentReader.get(SegmentReader.java:613) at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.(DirectoryReader.java:104) at org.apache.lucene.index.ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.(ReadOnlyDirectoryReader.java:27) at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader$1.doBody(DirectoryReader.java:74) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos$FindSegmentsFile.run(SegmentInfos.java:683) at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.open(DirectoryReader.java:69) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:476) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.open(IndexReader.java:403) at org.apache.solr.core.StandardIndexReaderFactory.newReader(StandardIndexReaderFactory.java:38) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1057) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.(SolrCore.java:579) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:137) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:83) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:943) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:778) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:504) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317) at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324) at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065) ) that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run Tomcat as a service it does not somehow consider CATALINA_OPTS set as a enviroment variable however everything is fine if I run tomcat on console/command line using startup.bat.
I have posted another question for my subsequent problem: [Tomcat as a service v/s Tomcat on console for 64 bit Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732996/tomcat-as-a-service-v-s-tomcat-on-console-for-64-bit-windows)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be treating this the same as any other OOME problem:

- It could be that your application just needs some more memory - Fix: increase the max heap size using the JVM -Xmx option.
- It could be that your application has a memory leak.  (Possibly in Solr, or possibly in your code.) - Fix: use a memory profiler to identify the leak and fix it.

---

> ... but then how come on a different server with exactly same system and solr configuration it is working fine?

Clearly they are not the same.  Something is different, but you can't figure out what it is.  (But I don't think that finding out what the difference is a good way to solve the problem.)

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Actually the issue is related to running Tomcat as a Service. I will post another question for it.

Answer (score 0):

How much more than 30G of RAM do you have in that server?

In any case, have you examined the RSS for the SOLR process in `top`? Run the `top` command, then press `M` (capital M) to sort the processes by memory use. Watch the Resident Set column to see how much SOLR actually uses as you load data, try various queries, and run `optimize` with various numbers for maxSegments. Start with a larger number and work downwards by roughly half or one third at a time. If you can get it down to 3 segments that is reasonable in a database that regularly gets new updates.

More details on optimize here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22

Answer (score 0):

Do both servers have the same application restart profile?

I recently came across a problem where the client application that was using SOLR was leaking classloaders across application restarts because the MultiThreadedHttpClientManager in the SOLR client library starts a ReferenceQueueThread and unless this is explicitly shutdown, the application classloader will be pinned, preventing it being reclaimed across restarts.

The workaround for this condition is to add a ServletContextListener that calls MultiThreadedHttpClientManager.shutdownAll() upon destroy.